# Service, Broadcast Receiver Instead of startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing a service and I've been following an example that unfortunately uses an Activity to get its work done.  The example uses startActivityForResult() to get values after doing something.  I'm wondering do I just use BroadcastReceiver to accomplish the same thing?  sendBroadcast(intent) and then capture the broadcast to do whatever?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for me is the best solution, but you can bind the service to the activity if you want another solution.